# SAP HANA Cloud Authorizations Management API - get list of tenant users for a subaccount

Tags: authorization, hana

Does anyone know how to retrieve the list of tenant users/portal users sign up in SAP HANA Cloud subaccount using Java?

I have referred the [SAP HANA Cloud Authorizations Management API](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/dbea343ebe184c26b6067daaabaa9ac6.html), but couldn't find a way to access it.

The API supports to get the list of assigned roles if we provide only the User ID. But I need to get the list of all user IDs.

Comment: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/08/30/how-to-manage-roles-assignments-to-users-in-hana-cloud-using-the-authorization-management-rest-api/

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I found this will be helpful.

SCIM REST API User Search

https://help.sap.com/viewer/6d6d63354d1242d185ab4830fc04feb1/Cloud/en-US/3af7dfae0aad4cf79ab8d822f8322e76.html